# Find a degree-4 polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that is not irreducible but also has no roots.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field, $f \in F[x]$ of degree 2 or 3.
Theorem: If $f$ has no roots, then $f$ is irreducible.

I have shown in several examples the above theorem holds. I am trying to find an example where the theorem does not hold in a degree-4 polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

The quartic polynomial that I have tried was $(x^4 - 22x^2 + 1)$. By the Rational Roots Theorem, the only possible rational roots for $(x^4 - 22x^2 + 1)$ are $\pm$1. But $(1)^4 - 22(1)^2 + 1 \neq 0$ and $(-1)^4 - 22(-1)^2 + 1 \neq 0$. Hence $(x^4 - 22x^2 + 1)$ has no roots. As I'm trying to show that $(x^4 - 22x^2 + 1)$ is reducible, I know that (from WolfRamAlpha) "A polynomial is said to be irreducible if it cannot be factored into nontrivial polynomials over the same field." So, if I can't factor $(x^4 - 22x^2 + 1)$ into nontrivial polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $(x^4 - 22x^2 + 1)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible. Since I don't know how to factor $(x^4 - 22x^2 + 1)$ into nontrivial polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, can I conclude that $(x^4 - 22x^2 + 1)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is reducible?

Comment: consider $(x^2+1)(x^2+2)$

Comment: Or more simply, $(x^2+1)^2$.

Comment: In the last two sentences, do you mean that if you can't factor, then it's irreducible, not reducible?

Comment: @GoranMalic Just edited it. Thanks

Comment: The last sentence still says reducible; other than that, it’s pretty much a repeat of the previous sentence

Comment: By using the rational root theorem, you are trying to factor your quartic into linear factors. Clearly you proved it can't be done, but there are still other ways to factor the quartic, like separating it into 2 quadratics.

Answer (score 1):

You can't conclude that your polynomial is irreducible until you *prove* that it cannot be factored nontrivially over $\Bbb Q$.  This will take some effort, presumably.

You could write $x^4-22x^2+1=(x^2+bx+c)(x^2+dx+e)$, get a system of equations, and try to solve it.

Namely, $\begin{cases} b+d=0\\bd+e+c=-22\\cd+eb=0\\ec=1\end{cases}$.

So, I get that $(c-e)d=0$, hence either $c=e=\pm1$ or $b=d=0$.

But $c=e=1\implies b=-24/d\implies d-24/d=0\implies d=\sqrt{24}\not\in\Bbb Q$. Similarly if $c=e=-1$.

On the other hand, $b=d=0\implies e+1/e=-22\implies e^2+22e+1=0$.  This gives again that $e$ is not rational, as the discriminant $480$ isn't a perfect square.

Alternatively, how about starting from the factorization, as in $((x-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2))^2=(x^2-2)^2=x^4-4x^2+4$?  Unlike the examples in the comments, here the roots are real.  Not that it matters.